# Script sends an object instead of a number

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below script sends an object instead of a number. I get in console:

> GET
>   http://localhost:8080/new_prog_22/paginator.action?page=[object%20Object]
>   500 (Internal Server Error)

I just need to send the `hash` variable which is a number because my links looks like

```
<a class="idPage" href="#4">4</a>
```

When I press the link I get in browser an alert notification `An error occurred! ' + thrownError`

Also I do not recive in cosnsole an output from `console.log("**** hash = "....`

script:

```
function paginFunc() {

    $( function() {
        $(window).on('hashchange', refreshByHash);
        var hash = window.location.hash; 
        hash = hash.substring(1);
        console.log("**** hash = " + hash + " ****");
        refreshByHash( hash );
    });


    function refreshByHash( hash ) {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'paginator.action?page=' + hash, // action to be perform
            type : 'GET', //type of posting the data
            dataType : 'html',
            async: true,
            success : function(htmlData) {
                $('#paginator').html(htmlData);
            },
            error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert('An error occurred! ' + thrownError);
            },
        });                   
    }

}
```

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the `$(document).ready()` (the short version of it) inside a function, which will only execute if the document is not ready at the time of calling the function. I suggest you move this code outside of `paginFunc`. Additionally, when the `hashchange` event fires on the `window`, the first parameter becomes the event data exposed by jQuery:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(event){
    //...
});
```

You need to move the part of the code that checks the hash inside your function. If you want to fire the handler too just like you did before, add `.triggerHandler('hashchange')` after the `.on()` call.

```
$(function(){
    $(window).on('hashchange', refreshByHash);
});

function refreshByHash(){
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1); 
    $.ajax({
        url: 'paginator.action?page=' + hash,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        async: true,
        success: function(htmlData) {
            $('#paginator').html(htmlData);
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('An error occurred! ' + thrownError);
        },
    });                   
}
```

If you *want* to keep the `hash` parameter, your handler needs to be changed, but I think you should **stick to the version above**.

```
$(function(){
    $(window).on('hashchange', function(event){
        refreshByHash(window.location.hash.substring(1));
    });
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    refreshByHash(hash);
});

function refreshByHash(hash){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'paginator.action?page=' + hash,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        async: true,
        success: function(htmlData) {
            $('#paginator').html(htmlData);
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('An error occurred! ' + thrownError);
        },
    });                   
}
```